# Убрать горизонтальный скролл на android с фиксированным body

Tags: адаптивная-верстка, media-queries

Заданы медиа запросы

```
 
@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) and (orientation: landscape)
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px)
```

Суть первого запроса в том, чтобы отображать ту версию сайта, которая открывается на компьютере при 768 (т.е. там установлена картинка 600 пикселей ширины, размер body 768 пикселей, все остальные блоки имеют процентный размер). При этом надо показывать без полосы прокрутки по ширине. При этом для 320-480 создана отдельная версия.
Также указано:

```
content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

На iOS все работает верно, но на android появляется горизонтальная полоса прокрутки и все показывается в увеличенном виде (надо, чтобы страница отображалась полностью по ширине). Как от этого избавиться либо решить эту задачу проще?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте заблокировать скролл при ширине 768 пикселей

```
overflow-x: hidden;
```

Comment: Не помогло, скрол исчез, но содержимое во весь экран по ширине не отобразилось.

Comment: @ЕленаСеменова а вы `content` в `meta` тег берете, или так и используете, как написано в вопросе?

Comment: Беру, stackoverflow.com с meta не пропускает

Comment: @ЕленаСеменова тогда попробуйте в `meta` прописать `content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width"`. К тому же лучше и картинку ставить в процентах.

Comment: Помогло с указанием width=768. Теперь надо придумать, как запускать это viewpoint только при горизонтальном положении 480. Скрипты, подменяющие элемент meta, не срабатывают.